# Very strange disconnections with TCP sockets

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, tcp

In short:
the server calls ::send() successfully but the data is not going out on the cable. The client send its quit command after some seconds because it does not receive any thing and that command is correctly received by the server.

In details:
The server send a command to its clients every 1/10 of second and an heartbeat each second. The clients only return an ack for the heartbeat. We modified the server application to log every command sent and received and we have recorded the pc's traffic with Wireshark. We can match every logged command to a TCP packet, until the problem kicks in. The problem only affects one client at a time. The data continues to flow normally with the other clients. The connection usually works a few minutes before getting into trouble. The connection should works from the moment the client boots until it is closed (ie days).

When the problem occurs, the log file contains the expected commands, but the Wireshark dump contains nothing. The image below show the traffic with one client. The red line is when the traffic stop, but the server continues to call ::send() successfully. [image: TCP traffic when the problem kicks in] After about 4 sec, the client timeout and it close the connection. It send a quit command and the server receive it normally.

What puzzle me even more is the packet containing the quit command is not acknowledged with a TCP ACK packet. It is as if the TCP connection is completely jammed on the sending end. The retransmission is an effect of that jam, but even the TCP SYN to establish a new connection is not correctly processed and does not get a simple TCP ACK.

After about 30 sec, the problem disappears and the SYN packet is finally accepted and the communication continues with the new connection.

This was tested on various Windows versions. During the tests, a remote desktop session was used and it never got disconnected by the same problem. It stays connected for hours without any problem. When the client pass through a wireless bridge, the problem is more frequent. We used Wireshark on both side of the wireless end-point and we see no retransmission or packet loss that can explain higher disconnection rate.

When many clients are connected to the same bridge, they do not fail at the same time. Only one at a time. So wireless noise does not seem to be an explication. We can see some retransmission in the Wireshark dump, but the communication continues as usual and there is no retransmission before the problem happens. An access point is connected to the server's switch. The client pc and server pc do not use a wireless network card.

For a long time, we tough the occasional disconnection was caused by the network, but more and more installations are wireless and the disconnections are now so frequent that they cause problems to the users.

We tried with and without Windows firewall enabled. We added the port exception even when the firewall is disabled. Neither the client or server have an anti-virus.

Comment: Hmm, 'It is as if the TCP connection is completely jammed on the sending end' sounds exactly right - the server tx window has closed up to prevent any further transmission until ACK received from client, but send() will succeed as long as there is buffering for its data at the server.  Client rx thread has got stuck somewhere?

Comment: But, from the wireshark dump, I see a receive window of 1002 bytes for the client, so it should not be that as far has I know. By the way, I don't know why the receive window is so small, but it works that way. The commands sent by the server have less bytes than that.

Comment: Receive window size 1002 is quite small. Was it initially 5840 bytes (like in the next SYN)? Because server calls send 10 times per seconds, maybe there is more than 1002 bytes in the sending buffer of server, and TCP stack waits an ACK because receive window (1002) does not allow sending of the next segment (1003 - 1460 bytes)

Comment: Yes it starts at 5840 bytes and it increases up to 64k during the first minutes, but, for some reason (probably wireless noise) it often decreases down to 1002 bytes. But it works for many minutes at 1002 bytes. The commands have 68 & 56 bytes in size, so they should pass. That Wireshark runs on the server pc and we see the last TCP ACK from the client. I also recorded on the client side and I do not see any packet sent but not received by the server pc.

Comment: Are there multiple interfaces on the boxes in question? I've had similar behavior in environments that assign the same IP to both the wireless and wired interface (not usually a good idea, but handy sometimes).

Comment: No, they only have one. Most of the boxes use DHCP.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I have a similar problem.

Comment: @meka We did not find the cause nor a solution. Hopefully, it was not too frequent in the field.

Answer (score 1):

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/#usingkeepalive may help.

Comment: Wheel, that's kind of part of the mystery. I already changed the keep alive to 1 sec during my experimentation (with 1 sec interval with a total of 10). In the normal case, it should not trigger because the heartbeat have to be acknowledged each second. I was hopping it would help (at least for the trouble shooting) during the 4 sec where nothing is happening but I do not see any "keep alive" packet in the dump.

Comment: Oups, I just saw the text "Remember that keepalive support [...] is not the default behavior in Linux." I have to check if I can manipulate the socket on the client side.

Comment: Yeah I had to activate keep alive in Ubuntu. They have a good C code example. I am actually trying to see if my server side can sense disconnection. I'll update you with any info if I am successful.